# how disable function: double space converting to point(dot) in EditText Java AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

when type space two times in the row it automatically converting(replacing) to dot(". ").
I want to disable this function only in my EditText

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following line in your XML. It works for me.

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

But generally from device keypad settings, you can disable the auto punctuation.